# How upgrade BIOS for HP 550 Laptop

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, bios

I am owner an old HP Laptop. About HW/BIOS:
`cat /sys/class/dmi/id/bios_version` yields `68MVU Ver. F.02`. `cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial` yields `CNU8463MW4`. Can I upgrade BIOS to current version (F.20)? How do I do that? Is that possible? I use on this Laptop only Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit version (no Windows). The reason for this is that after awakening from suspend laptop fan turns full sometimes and I have to restart OS. I have standard kernel. At previous kernels it was the same. Although laptop is old he does his job well.
EDIT: I have following this instructions: [Flashing BIOS from Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Flashing_BIOS_from_Linux).There is a note for HP users. It will be linked to question that has an [Accepted Solution](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/How-to-update-BIOS-on-Linux/m-p/5441775#M1205498) (although the on HP website opens slow). I have download .*exe-file from HP and extracted this with `7zip`. In extracted `exe` file there is no `bin` file. I have downloaded a file for Windows XP `sp55872.exe`.

Comment: Follow the instructions at the HP's website where you download the BIOS. Usually there's at least one method that is OS agnostic.

Comment: @GabrielGarcia - I did not come clear by HP support website.

Comment: So please [edit] your question to include the link to the instructions and explain what isn't clear for you.

Comment: I have edited my question.